# Yii 2 MSSQL QueryBuilder

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I try to build query and fetch records from MSSQL database. I created yii\db\Query object to prepare query string:

```
$query = new Query;
$query->select(['Name', 'PositionX', 'PositionY'])
    ->from('mydb.dbo.position')
    ->addOrderBy('PositionX DESC')
    ->limit(100);
```

after that, I added Query object to yii\db\mssql\QueryBuilder

```
$qb = new QueryBuilder(\Yii::$app->db_mssql);
$qb->build($query);
```

and now I need to fetch records as model eg:

```
$result = Position::findAll($qb);
```

but `findAll()` throw error:

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'Object of class
>   yii\db\mssql\QueryBuilder could not be converted to string Failed to
>   prepare SQL: SELECT * FROM [mydb].[dbo].[position] WHERE [Name]=:qp0'

so how should I do this? :)

Comment: use find(http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-model/) method for easy query writing

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing function between different type of db access  strategy

You could use a create command as

```
$myPositions = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT Name, PositionX, PositionY 
              FROM position order PositionX DESC limit 100 ')
           ->queryAll();
```

or  you should use a ActiveRecord assuming your have a model class Posotion for your Position table

```
$myPositions  = Position::find()
      ->select(['Name', 'PositionX', 'PositionY'])
      ->from('mydb.dbo.position')
      ->orderBy('PositionX DESC')
      ->limit(100)->all();
```

or use query builder

```
$myPositions = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Name', 'PositionX', 'PositionY'])
    ->from('mydb.dbo.position')
    ->orderBy('PositionX DESC')
    ->limit(100)
    ->all();
```

Comment: Yes it's look promising, but:
a) Yii::$app->db->createCommand() is ok, but I don't like to build simple query from strings (when moving from one version of DB to another, you will spend hours rewriting code)
b) This is the correct answer :)
c) Will not work for MSSQL without yii\db\mssql\QueryBuilder(), because it will create 
"SELECT `Name` FROM `mydb`. `dbo `. `position`"  `
query with `, but MSSQL expected [
"SELECT [Name] FROM [mydb].[dbo].[position]"

Thanks for answer!

Comment: One more thing, if table does not have model, than my approach from first comment is correct, I just had to list returned array from QueryBuilder->build() :) and then use it in eg createCommand()

Comment: i don't undestand you comment  .. explain better please  .